# CSS vertical align block in a container

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

[fiddle](http://tinyurl.com/ojufxu8)

Any way to align all `.col` to the top, matching the height of their siblings above?

Comment: You need a Masonary layout?

Comment: no I dont, what is that?

Comment: The col will be adjusted to fill the remaining space, that is what Masonary layout is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my **current solution** for maintaining equal height and width.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">...</div>
    <div class="col">...</div>
</div>

.row {
    display: flex; /* assigns equal height to all the children */
}

.col {
    flex: 1; /* assigns, equal width*/
}
```

This is the solution for **backwards support** for browser such as IE8,9 :

```
.row {
    display: table;
}

.col {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%; /* depends on the number of columns, 50% for two col, 25% for four column and so on*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, any way to get it working without flex thought, for backwards support?

Comment: You can use table layout